# Angular navigation routing

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to recover id and another parameter to be able to display it in another component, I have a component where I inject an angular material table and this is the problem I don't know how to do to recover parameters. if someone has a solution.

Thanks in advance.

**list.components.ts**

```
makeRowObservable(): Obervable<any[]> {
  return this.service
   .get()
    .pipe(
      map((data: Istud) => {
      data.stud.map((item:any[]) => this.transormListToMap(item)
      }
}
    
    transormListToMap() {
    
        let result = {};
        for (let i = 0; i < this.tableCols.length; i++) {
            let col = this.tableCols[i];
            let value = item[i];
            let colId = col.key;
            result[colId] = value;
        }
        return result; // 
    }

   passData() {
   this.router.navigate([/route, // i need param here]);
  }
```

**list.component.html**

```
<app-table>
 [tableCols]="tableCols"
 (click)="passData()" // how to get id here ?
 [tableRows]="rows | async"
</app-table>
```

Comment: Where should that param come from? `tableCols[i].key`?

Comment: By click, do you mean row click?

Comment: I am a beginner I just want to get the id

Comment: anyone can help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you navigate, set the state object:

```
this.router.navigate([/route] {state:{YOURID: VALUE-OF-ID}});
```

When you initialize the component that you require the id:

```
if(this.history.state){
this.propertyInTheNewComponent = this.history.state.YOURID
}
```

Comment: I have a table with several data it is necessary that the id that I recover is dynamic

Comment: so that state can be an object with all of the parameters that you need